# dynamically selecting closest <ul> when button presses

Tags: javascript

In a html page, I have number of buttons given by the following html:

```
<div class="container text-center">
  <h1>Mic Recorder to Mp3 Example</h1>
  <p>Check your web developer tool console.</p>
  <button class="btn btn-primary">Start recording</button>
  <ul id="playlist"></ul>
</div>

<div class="container text-center">
  <h1>Mic Recorder to Mp3 Example</h1>
  <p>Check your web developer tool console.</p>
  <button class="btn btn-primary">Start recording</button>
  <ul id="playlist"></ul>
</div>

<div class="container text-center">
  <h1>Mic Recorder to Mp3 Example</h1>
  <p>Check your web developer tool console.</p>
  <button class="btn btn-primary">Start recording</button>
  <ul id="playlist"></ul>
</div>
```

A vanilla javascript is used to fire function for each button press. now an li is appended to the ul called #playlist. Now I want the ul near by the button pressed is to be selected in  document.querySelector('#playlist').appendChild(li);
How to achieve this?

The full code is below:

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
const recorder = new MicRecorder({
  bitRate: 128
});

buttons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', startRecording));

function startRecording() {
  recorder.start().then(() => {
    buttons.forEach(button => {
      button.textContent = 'Stop recording';
      button.classList.toggle('btn-danger');
      button.removeEventListener('click', startRecording);
      button.addEventListener('click', stopRecording);
    });
  }).catch((e) => {
    console.error(e);
  });
}

function stopRecording() {
  recorder.stop().getMp3().then(([buffer, blob]) => {
    console.log(buffer, blob);
    const file = new File(buffer, 'music.mp3', {
      type: blob.type,
      lastModified: Date.now()
    });

    const li = document.createElement('li');
    const player = new Audio(URL.createObjectURL(file));
    player.controls = true;
    li.appendChild(player);

    document.querySelector('#playlist').appendChild(li);
    buttons.forEach(button => {
      button.textContent = 'Start recording';
      button.classList.toggle('btn-danger');
      button.removeEventListener('click', stopRecording);
      button.addEventListener('click', startRecording);
    });
  }).catch((e) => {
    console.error(e);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question correctly you could use `closest()` method.

> The `closest()` method traverses the `Element` and its parents (heading toward the document root) until it finds a node that matches the provided selector string. Will return itself or the matching ancestor. If no such element exists, it returns `null`.

[Here is a LINK to the MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest#:%7E:text=The%20closest()%20method%20traverses,element%20exists%2C%20it%20returns%20null%20.)

Comment: when i do like document.querySelector.closest('#playlist').appendChild(li); it says querySelector.closest() is not a function..any idea?

Comment: closest() requires 1 argument ```var closestElement = targetElement.closest(selectors);```

Comment: Yes, doing closest('li') too did not give out anything. same with document.querySelector('#playlist').appendChild.closest(li);

Comment: Not sure why the downvote... but based on your last comment not sure _document.querySelector('#playlist').appendChild.closest(li);_ will do what you're trying to do. If you are trying to find the nearest 'ul' from 'li' ```let closestUl = document.querySelector('li').closest('ul')```

Comment: Thanks for that, i need to identify the div where the button is pressed and populate the #playlist within that div.